# I can't install pylibmc in virtual enviroment with Python 3.4.0

Tags: python, pip, pylibmc

First of all I use Ubuntu 17.10 and I downloaded previous version of python - python 3.4.0 because this older version is required in my project. I installed both `memcached` and `libmemcached-dev` and **I can install without issues `pylibmc` in virtual env based on python 3.6.3.**

However during installing `pylibmc` in enviroment based on `Python 3.4.0` I get erros:

```
    Collecting pylibmc==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/f4/3904b7171e61a83eafee0ed3b1b8efe4d3c6ddc05f7ebdff1831cf0e15f1/pylibmc-1.5.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pylibmc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pylibmc ... error
  Complete output from command /home/przemek/usosApi34/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-859hcscx/pylibmc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-_u6qlw_7 --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  copying src/pylibmc/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  copying src/pylibmc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  copying src/pylibmc/client.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  copying src/pylibmc/consts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  copying src/pylibmc/test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  copying src/pylibmc/pools.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
  running build_ext
  building '_pylibmc' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE_ZLIB -I/home/przemek/opt/python-3.4.0/include/python3.4m -c src/_pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘PylibMC_Client_init’:
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:209:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
       int native_serialization, native_deserialization;
       ^~~
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘_PylibMC_deserialize_native’:
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:642:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
       PyObject *retval = NULL;
       ^~~~~~~~
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘PylibMC_Client_gets’:
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:785:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
       int miss = 0;
       ^~~
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘_PylibMC_SerializeValue’:
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1168:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
       int success;
       ^~~
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘_PylibMC_serialize_native’:
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1247:9: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
           const char *value_str = (value_obj == Py_True) ? "1" : "0";
           ^~~~~
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1252:9: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
           PyObject *tmp = PyObject_Str(value_obj);
           ^~~~~~~~
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘PylibMC_Client_get_multi’:
  src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1793:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
       Py_ssize_t key_idx = 0;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
  cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pylibmc
  Running setup.py clean for pylibmc
Failed to build pylibmc
Installing collected packages: pylibmc
  Running setup.py install for pylibmc ... error
    Complete output from command /home/przemek/usosApi34/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-859hcscx/pylibmc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-1r6f9jsj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/przemek/usosApi34/include/site/python3.4/pylibmc:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    copying src/pylibmc/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    copying src/pylibmc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    copying src/pylibmc/client.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    copying src/pylibmc/consts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    copying src/pylibmc/test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    copying src/pylibmc/pools.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylibmc
    running build_ext
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE_ZLIB -I/home/przemek/opt/python-3.4.0/include/python3.4m -c src/_pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘PylibMC_Client_init’:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:209:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
         int native_serialization, native_deserialization;
         ^~~
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘_PylibMC_deserialize_native’:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:642:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
         PyObject *retval = NULL;
         ^~~~~~~~
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘PylibMC_Client_gets’:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:785:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
         int miss = 0;
         ^~~
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘_PylibMC_SerializeValue’:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1168:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
         int success;
         ^~~
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘_PylibMC_serialize_native’:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1247:9: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
             const char *value_str = (value_obj == Py_True) ? "1" : "0";
             ^~~~~
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1252:9: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
             PyObject *tmp = PyObject_Str(value_obj);
             ^~~~~~~~
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘PylibMC_Client_get_multi’:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1793:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
         Py_ssize_t key_idx = 0;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/przemek/usosApi34/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-859hcscx/pylibmc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-1r6f9jsj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/przemek/usosApi34/include/site/python3.4/pylibmc" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-859hcscx/pylibmc/
```

Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: Just a note: `setup.py` specifically uses the [`-std=c99` compiler flag](https://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/blob/1.5.1/setup.py#L77) so that this error doesn't appear. So it appears the compiler must be not getting or ignoring this flag...

Comment: This may be related to [Python issue 21121](https://bugs.python.org/issue21121) Can you try running `export CFLAGS=$(python3.4 -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var("CFLAGS").replace("-Werror=declaration-after-statement",""))')` before `pip install`?

Comment: @NilsWerner, You are right. You can add an answer. Thank you buddy!

Comment: Can you also try to run `CFLAGS=-Wno-error=declaration-after-statement pip install ...`? Preferrably in a new shell in which you didn't run the `export` line from before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [a bug in Python 3.4](https://bugs.python.org/issue21121) that accidentally sets the `CFLAG` to contain `-Werror=declaration-after-statement` for all build steps. The errors you are seeing are a result of this flag being set. The solution is to manually unset it during `pip install`

```
CFLAGS=-Wno-error=declaration-after-statement pip install pylibmc==1.5.1
```